# Populate _link() target url with href value using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

How can I get the value of the href attribute in a link to populate the _link() target url value using jquery?

This is the normal code:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.mydomain.com/gallery']); return false;">Gallery</a>
```

There are many links that need to be updated in this fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class for the links you would like to run `_gaq.push` for and then use jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the click event to them.

Give your links a class like `gaq`:

```
<a class="gaq" href="http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/">Gallery</a>
```

And use jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to give all links with this class the ability to run the push function on click.

```
$('.gaq').live('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_link', $(this).attr("href")]);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That seems like a good approach. Is it possible to access the attr value from within the push function like this? onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', $('a').attr('href')]); return false;"

Comment: The $(this) selector inside the context of live is the jQuery selector of the element clicked on.  So $(this).attr("href") will return the href value of what the user clicked.

Comment: Gotcha, I was curious if it was possible to avoid the live code and just put everything inline with the onclick attribute, like this: onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', $(this).attr('href')]); return false;"

Comment: I see what you mean.  onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', $(this).attr('href')]); return false;" will work the way you think it does.

Comment: Using your method without the inline code is much cleaner, so I am going with that. Thank you.

Comment: `$(this).attr("href")` is unnecessary. `this.href` is perfectly sufficient and probably preferred for all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

i would say the easiest way is to add a class to the <a>, then access it through the id.

```
$('.aClass').attr('href') //gets the value of the href
$('.aClass').attr('href', 'stackoverflow.com') //sets the value of the href

$('.aClass').click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_link', $(this).attr('href')]); 
    return false;
});
```

Hope that helps. You can change the value of the attr (attribute) to access or edit its value.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I forgot specify that there are many many links, so something more generic may work better.

Comment: If I need to access multiple things, then i normally use a jquery selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). I don't know if anchors are supported so you could add a class and then access each one through the class $('.aClass').attr('href')

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for all of your insights. This solution worked:

Comment: onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', $('a').attr('href')]); return false;"

Comment: @sterling. Thanks for the reply. Appreciate the thanks. Glad i could help.

Comment: It seems the addition of the .live function as mentioned by Jeff makes things work as intended. Thank you again.

Comment: @sterling I was hoping to take advantage of your script and apply the same technique to the same thing I'm trying to do with my post here. Would you be able to take a look and provide any assistance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886015/jquery-cross-domain-tracking-with-google-analytics-asynchronous-syntax